# Client certificate

Tags: openssl

I build a client software to communicate with server.The connection should be secured(SSL)
I use openssl library for linux .During the SSL handshaking the server ask my client certificate but I don't have one.When I connect with my browser to that server the browser
keeps certificate and I found it.Than I put it in my source like this:

```
if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "client.crt", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

But server still send me request for my client certificate and drop connection.I suppose that I need one more file - key file that I have to send but I don't know where to find it.
Could anyone help?

Comment: Are you asking the community for the value of your private key?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can locate your private key, you can simply load it with `int SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *file, int type`.

Comment: Do you mean that I should generate my own key file?It doesn't work.I tried.Because the client certificate and private-key doesn't match.I use function SSL_CTX_check_private_key() to see that.

Answer (score 0):

As Jumbogram stated, you have to load the matching private key to the certificate file you are attempting to load.  You can't just generate a new key and use that, as the key and the certificate signed with that key won't match.

Instead, generate a new key and certificate pair using openssl, and point the SSL_CTX_* functions to those.